# Release Notes for 12.1.1

Tags: version-12.1

I've just received an email informing me that 12.1.1 is available. I can't see any release notes for this. Are there any? Is there any information on what's been fixed?

Comment: There is none I could find, other than ofcourse the revision history.  https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html  may be because it is minor release, there is no "official" release notes, or may be there is, but not released yet.

Comment: @Nasser Please post it as an answer, those *are* the release notes. If there are other, more detailed notes, someone can still post a new answer.

Comment: This is probably obvious, but that main change is that lots of bugs were fixed. I don't expect they'll publish a list of fixed bugs (but maybe there are more detailed release notes). I was beta testing the 12.1.1 builds and I was quite happy about several fixed (though I don't recall all of them). When you reported a bug, usually they'll send an email when a new release fixes it. I got many such emails recently.

Comment: How can we pull this update? Can you please clarify this point?

Comment: @CATrevillian I had to buy a service license to qualify for the free update, but you should check your products on the user portal to see if the "Free Update" button appears next to your copy of 12.1.

Comment: @flinty thank you! I wonder if we will have another “Free Update” button you click for 12.1.1(.1) hah!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only release notes I know about are given at

[quick-revision-history](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html)

[image]

May be more can be found at other pages.

Notice what is says **It includes almost a thousand bug fixes** which I think is amazing accomplishment.  It would have been nice though to see the list of such bug fixes. It is always useful to know what was fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not, at least for now.

Comment: You can see some [here](https://twitter.com/stephen_wolfram/status/1273609460376915969), unfortunately the whole image is too low-res!